# Realm Update from WPF EventTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, realm

I have a WPF datagrid that is bound to a [Realm](http://realm.io) backed object. The grid has an autocomplete box that allows the user to enter/select an account number which should then update the source object and the UI. Instead, when a selection is made, the UI box goes back to empty and the stored object is not updated. [The Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#writes) states `Modifying the collection (e.g. adding or removing items) must happen in a write transaction`, so somehow, when the user makes a selection I need to trigger a write transaction on that specific row object. This is further confirmed by the error in the output window

`System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=SAccount; DataItem='TransactionDetails' (HashCode=24381833); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object') RealmInvalidTransactionException:'Realms.Exceptions.RealmInvalidTransactionException: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.`

I am trying to use an EventTrigger bound to a command in my VM but the trigger never fires. Can someone explain (or maybe even quickly demonstrate) how to make this work?

In my ViewModel I'm retreiving the object like this:

`Transaction = realm.All<Transaction>().Where( t => t.ID == tid ).First();`

and then binding it in my XAML view

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TransactionDataGrid" 
      DataGridCell.Selected="TransactionDataGrid_GotFocus" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      CanUserSortColumns="True"
      CanUserReorderColumns="False"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="10,0,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Height="556" 
      Width="1012" 
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Transaction.Rows}"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Source" Header="Source Account" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="AccountNum" Header="Account Number" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding SAccount.RawAccountNumber}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox 
                            Background="AliceBlue"
                            IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                            FilterMode="Contains"
                            MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                            ValueMemberPath="RawAccountNumber"
                            PreviewTextInput="AutoCompleteBox_PreviewTextInput"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SAccount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Text="{Binding Path=SAccount.RawAccountNumber}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Accounts}" >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateRowCommand}"
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ID}"/><!-- the command parameter should be the ID of the row we are updating? -->
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RawAccountNumber}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                    </StackPanel>
```

The command in my ViewModel

```
public ICommand UpdateRowCommand
{
    set
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Hello UpdateRowCommand" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where’s the getter for the VM command property? The trigger doesn’t call the setter for the command property, the binding will call the getter and when the trigger executes, the ICommand you return from the getter will have its Execute() method called.

Comment: Thanks @DaveM. That was pretty silly on my part. I updated the ICommand and now it fires. Now I need to get the params to do the update.